# Conic projection view transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, user-interface

I am building a custom map viewer, part of meteorological production system, using Java language and GeoTools library. I have prepared a custom map renderer, using OpenGL, that allows to display maps in different projections and need a bit of help with user camera navigation over maps in Lambert conic projection.

I would like to allow user to navigate the conic map in such way, that map north is always pointing up.
Moving mouse left and right should rotate the map around a pole, and moving up/down is always north-south adjustment:

[image: User viewport alignment example]

I am struggling with understanding the mathematical transformation for screen-map coordinates for such use case, could anyone point me to the right direction?

This is a code I am trying right now; It only accounts for x axis mouse movement for now:

- origin vector is north pole location
- worldPos and prevWorldPos are mouse positions
- all vectors are in projection coordinate system

  ```
  float pdx = prevWorldPos.x - origin.x;
  float pdy = prevWorldPos.y - origin.y;

  float radius = (float) Math.sqrt( pdx*pdx + pdy*pdy );

  float prevAngle = (float) Math.atan2(pdy, pdx);
  float da = (float) Math.atan2(radius, worldPos.x - prevWorldPos.x);

  float angle = prevAngle + da;

  cameraAngle = angle+Angles.PI_div_2;

  cameraX = origin.x + (float) (radius * Math.cos( angle ));
  cameraY = origin.y + (float) (radius * Math.sin( angle ));
  ```

Comment: Welcome! Please take the community tour:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and edit your question to include details--what software are you using? If building something on your own, what language?  Please include what you have tried and specifically what you are struggling with--screen shots and code samples help.

Comment: please show us what code you have tried already

Comment: thanks, edited the question... it is about math transformation, disregarding the actual GIS platform. Just a user interaction case

Comment: Added some sample code, where I am trying to account only for mouse x axis movement... I feel like I lack the whole transformation understanding, so it may be useless.